# Filtering json values

Tags: json, node.js

I have a process that returns a json object:

```
data={key1:[], key2:[], key3:[{key1:"a"}, {key2:"b"}], key4:[{key1:"c"}, {key2:"d"}]}
```

I want know if there is a simple way to filter this json object to remove the properties where the value is an empty array.

Once filtered I can then loop through the remaining properties and action the array elements.

Comment: Ok, so, it actually returns an object. and you want to remove keys from that object that have an empty array. that should be pretty easy to search for. Split it into two parts, finding empty object properties, and deleting object properties.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we have to iterate over properties in an object.

```
for (var prop in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        // Logic here 
    }
}
```

Then it's a simple check to filter out empty array properties

```
if (data[prop].length == 0) {
    delete data[prop]
}
```

The full solution,

```
for (var prop in data) {
    if (data.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        if (data[prop].length == 0) {
            delete data[prop]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: why do we need the hasOwnProperty(prop) check if we are already iterating over the properties in the for loop?

Comment: When I output the json object before and after your code using console.log(data) there is no difference, have I misunderstood?

Comment: prop.length appears to evaluation the number of characters in the key, not the value of the associated array?

Comment: The `hasOwnProperty(prop)` check ensures that we are only iterating over the properties exclusive to `data`. You may recall that all JavaScript objects inherit from Object.prototype, there wouldn't be much point in iterating over prototype properties in this case. See this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype

My code had an error. Instead of checking the length of the value (`data[prop]`), I was erroneously checking the length of the key (`prop`) itself. Code fixed. Please do share the error message if something is still off.

Comment: As hasOwnProperty ensure we are not checking the prototype properties for for in only cycle through the object too and not the prototype properties?

Comment: Yes. See **Description** here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Answer (score 0):

I would prefer to create a new object that omits the empty arrays instead of deleting from the existing object.

```
var data={key1:[], key2:[], key3:[{key1:"a"}, {key2:"b"}], key4:[{key1:"c"}, {key2:"d"}]}

var cleanData = Object.keys(data).reduce((obj, key) => {
    if (data[key] && data[key].length) {
        obj[key] = data[key]
    }
    return obj
}, {})
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `lodash` should make this pretty simple:

```
var filtered = _.omitBy(data, function(value) {
    return Array.isArray(value) && value.length == 0;
});
```

You can now loop through the remaining elements in the filtered object to take further actions on them.

Comment: What's the issue with this solution?

Answer (score 0):

**Try this working demo :**

```js
var data = {
             key1:[], 
             key2:[], 
             key3:[
                    {key1:"a"}, 
                    {key2:"b"}
                  ], 
             key4:[
                  {key1:"c"}, 
                    {key2:"d"}
                  ]
};

for (var i in data) {
    if (data[i].length == 0) {
      delete data[i]
    }
}

console.log(data);
```